# What is the meaning of an 8 followed by a dotted line?

Tags: piano, notation, ottava

[image: "Guardian Battle Theme" from The Legend of Zelda: Breath of the Wild, mm. 1-7]

There is a 8 and a bunch of dots going over the notes. it doesn't look like octave lines, though.

Comment: That's what octave lines look like. Why do you say different?

Answer (score 6):

It's an ottava-line. Or shorter: an 8va line. It means you should play those notes one octave higher than notated.

There's also an 8vb-line (ottava bassa) to play the notes an octave lower, which is drawn underneath the staff.

And then there's the same for 2 octaves too: 15ma and 15mb
Which stands for 'quindicessima' and 'quindicessima bassa' or a 15th up or down respectively.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123229/discussion-on-answer-by-creynders-what-is-the-meaning-of-an-8-followed-by-a-dott).